# center above line text on a specific character in Gregorio

Tags: gregorio

In the lyrics, you can align a letter of a word with a note by using the {}.

```
Ce{n}ter(g)
```

This will place the 'n' of 'Center' under the note.

Is there a way to do this with abovelinetext?
I tried

```
<alt>Ce{n}ter</alt>(g)
```

but it fails.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to center a translation below the text of the words (not the notes). But it doesn’t look like you can center abovelinestext. It is aligned to the first note when using  tags (the preferred way if I’m not mistaken) or the next note if you use [alt:].

By the way there is a macro to center lyrics on the syllable. You should refer to the documentation of your installation. (Using braces is largely inefficient if you’re doing it for an entire score.)